# Правильно ли расставлены запятые в данном предложении? (2)

Tags: пунктуация

*Там, на Клондайке, на недавно открытых приисках каждый сможет мгновенно разбогатеть.*

Comment: Правильно......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Там, на Клондайке, на недавно открытых приисках каждый сможет мгновенно разбогатеть.**

  *"Там"* и *"на недавно открытых приисках"* — неоднородные обстоятельства; *"на Клондайке"* — уточнение к *"там"*, поэтому
  выделяется запятыми.
- Возможен ещё вариант:

  **Там — на Клондайке, на недавно открытых приисках, — каждый сможет мгновенно разбогатеть.**

  Здесь *"на недавно открытых приисках"* — это пояснение к *"Клондайку"*, а
  вся конструкция вместе, выделенная тире, — это уточнение к *"там"*.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133705/discussion-on-answer-by-nektoid-------).